# Vue in nativescript

Tags: nativescript-vue

Is possible to have a component inside another component in nativescript vue?
Like relation father-son

Like this:

```
<Frame ~mainContent>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Initial Page" style="color:white">
            <NavigationButton icon="res://menu" @tap="openMenu"></NavigationButton>
        </ActionBar>

        <StackLayout>
           <son-component></son-component>
        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel—have you tried it? If so, what results does it give you?

Comment: Yes, i tried and got this error "[TypeError: No known component for element div.]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. You need to register Son Component

```
<Frame ~mainContent>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Initial Page" style="color:white">
            <NavigationButton icon="res://menu" @tap="openMenu"></NavigationButton>
        </ActionBar>

        <StackLayout>
           <Son></Son>
        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
</Frame>

<script >
import Son from "./son-component";

  export default {
    components: {
    Son,
  },
    props: {

  },
  data() {

  }
}
</script>
```